# Complexity of a function with 1 loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Can anyone tell me what's the complexity of the below function? And how to calculate the complexity?

I am suspecting that it's O(log(n)) or  O(sqrt(N)).
My reasoning was based on taking examples of n=4, n=8, n=16 and I found that the loop will take log(n) but I don't think it'll be enough since sqrt also will give the same values so I need to work on bigger values of n, so I am not sure how to approach this.

I had this function in the exam today.

```
void f(int n){
     int i=1;
     int j=1;
     while(j <= n){
         i += 1;
         j += i;
     }
}
```

Comment: I meant that my guess is that it's O(log(n)) or O(sqrt(n)) not that I don't remember the answer xD

Comment: State your reasoning and ask if you are right. This usually gets a more favorable result because if you aren't right, we can correct the error in your reasoning so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: My reasoning was based on taking examples of n=4, n=8, n=16 and I found that the loop will take log(n) but I don't think it'll be enough since sqrt also will give the same values, so I am not sure how to approach this :/

Comment: Hint: `j` follows the pattern of [Triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: yes I figured that out but am still not sure how to get the complexity from there

Comment: Minor note: `function` makes no sense in your function's definition. Presumably it should be replaced with `void` to make it legal C++.

Comment: Ah yes I changed it, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence `j` goes through is `1 3 6 10 15 21`, aka the triangular numbers, aka `n*(n+1)/2`.

Expanded, this is `( n^2 + n ) / 2`. We can ignore the scaling ( `/ 2`) and linear ( `+ n`) factors, which leaves us with `n^2`.

`j` grows as a `n^2` polynomial, so the loop will stop after the inverse of that growth:

The time complexity is **O(sqrt(n))**

Comment: Well understood thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I wrote a small program that attempts to illustrate whether this is O(log(N)) or O(sqrt(N)) by actually counting how many iterations of your loop execute. This seemed a reasonable approximation given that the body of the loop is largely negligible (simply incrementing two integer variables).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int f(int n)
{
    int i=1;
    int j=1;
    int count = 0;

    while(j <= n){
        i += 1;
        j += i;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
        int count = pow(10, ii);
        int rc = f(count);
        char *fmt = "N=%d^%-2d -> %d, log(N)=%.2f, sqrt(N)=%.2f\n";
        printf(fmt, 10, ii, rc, log(count), sqrt(count));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running this code results in the following output:

```
N=10^0  -> 1, log(N)=0.00, sqrt(N)=1.00
N=10^1  -> 4, log(N)=2.30, sqrt(N)=3.16
N=10^2  -> 13, log(N)=4.61, sqrt(N)=10.00
N=10^3  -> 44, log(N)=6.91, sqrt(N)=31.62
N=10^4  -> 140, log(N)=9.21, sqrt(N)=100.00
N=10^5  -> 446, log(N)=11.51, sqrt(N)=316.23
N=10^6  -> 1413, log(N)=13.82, sqrt(N)=1000.00
N=10^7  -> 4471, log(N)=16.12, sqrt(N)=3162.28
N=10^8  -> 14141, log(N)=18.42, sqrt(N)=10000.00
N=10^9  -> 44720, log(N)=20.72, sqrt(N)=31622.78
```

So, for example, you can see that when N=10^9, the number of iterations is 44720, which is much greater than log(N) (20.72) but quite close to sqrt(N) (31622.78).

Answer (score -2):

It is depended your condition. In other words, the time complexity is O(sqrt(n)).
How many statements are executed, relative to input size n? Often,
but NOT always, we can get an idea from the number of times a loop
iterates. The loop body executes for i= 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + .... + 2^n; and this
sequence has O(sqrt(n)) values.

Check the ["Introduction to Algorithms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) book about more details.

Comment: i seq is `1 2 3 4 ..` and j seq is `1 3 6 10 15 21 ...`. There is no `2^0 2^1 ... 2^n` sequence.